# Inherit from a partial class C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a partial class that inherits from another partial class in C#, when I create the instance I can't access the public/protected methods from base class.

Note: the class in the first namespace is from a regular .Net Class Library, the second one is from a .Net Portable Class library. I'm using the no portable library as reference in the portable project.

```
namespace carnamespace
public partial class Car{}

namespace carnamespacePortable
public partial class Car : carnamespace.Car{}
```

Comment: I wouldn't think you can have a portable library dependent on a non-portable library.

Comment: The fact that it's a partial class has nothing to do with it. The individual components of a partial class are combined into a regular class by the compiler. That said, partial classes should be used **only** for designer-generated code; anything else is a misuse. If you have a class that's so big that you think splitting it into multiple partial classes is a good idea, it's a clear indication of a design problem because that class is doing too much.

Comment: @DanielMann I understand what are you saying, my need is to reuse code from the no portable class in the portable class through a base class, instead of create the same methods just to make reference to the same method in the no portable class

Comment: I just have to comment on the naming. Its screaming of namespace ambiguity problems with base and derived classes sharing the same name - perhaps that's why you *can't access the public/protected methods from base class.*

Comment: @DanielMann - "That said, partial classes should be used only for designer-generated code; anything else is a misuse" - No, that's not true. It's a compile feature. You can use it whenever you like. It's just that the designer also uses it.

Comment: Are you trying to access the child class's methods from the parent or vice versa?

Comment: @DevinLiu I'm trying to use methods from base class in the child class through inherit them, but they don't appear when I instance the child class, only the methods from object class appear

Comment: Why not make a subclass that inherits from your class?